# Pointer problem using functions from non-object API in objects

Tags: c++, function, pointers, member

I am writing some C++ code to get data from a SDR (software defined radio) and analyse it using an FFT library (FFTW3). The software uses an API (SDR_play_API and its DLL). *I am trying to include the API functionality into an object.* The library comes with a non-object based example program.

The IDE I am using is VS2105.

Three of the functions are callbacks to handle events from the hardware. The address of the callback functions that handle these events are passed to the API through a structure. *I include the relevant code snippets from the example program, the header files and my own code after a description of the problem.*

Though I have been on some C++ training - and taught others the basics - I am far from an expert and the problem goes beyond my understanding of pointers and objects.

The problem I have is one that has been discussed before on Stack Exchange. *It is a problem of pointers to member functions.*

The simple solution would seem to be to make the functions STATICs. However that causes problems because of some of the variables used in these functions. Without making them static then the compiler complains and if I make them static the linker complains because there is no matching definition for static variables in the library.

I have looked through Stack Exchange tried the solutions suggested but I can't seem to make any of them work - I get compiler errors.

So I feel ideally I just want to pass the pointers to the member functions to API through the structure ... but I have tried all sorts of variations on syntax without success. Can anyone help?

The API comes with an example program that does not use objects. So before I reveal my attempts to use the functions in an object, here is the code from the example program. First I will show where it assigns the location of the functions to the members of the structure, then I will include the structure definitions etc from the header file.

First then, the assignment:

```
    // Assign callback functions to be passed to sdrplay_api_Init()
    cbFns.StreamACbFn = StreamACallback;
    cbFns.StreamBCbFn = StreamBCallback;
    cbFns.EventCbFn = EventCallback;
```

Here, from the header file that comes with the API, is the definition of the structure

```
{
sdrplay_api_StreamCallback_t StreamACbFn;
sdrplay_api_StreamCallback_t StreamBCbFn;
sdrplay_api_EventCallback_t  EventCbFn;
} sdrplay_api_CallbackFnsT;
```

and here, again from the header file that comes with the API is the definition of the data types - you can see the these are function pointers

```
typedef void (*sdrplay_api_StreamCallback_t)(short *xi, short *xq, sdrplay_api_StreamCbParamsT *params, unsigned int numSamples, unsigned int reset, void *cbContext); 
typedef void (*sdrplay_api_EventCallback_t)(sdrplay_api_EventT eventId, sdrplay_api_TunerSelectT tuner, sdrplay_api_EventParamsT *params, void *cbContext);
```

here is one of the call back function declarations

```
    void StreamACallback(short *xi, short *xq, sdrplay_api_StreamCbParamsT *params, unsigned int numSamples, unsigned int reset, void *cbContext)
{
...
}
```

So that all works fine and compiles - but it that works in a non-object scenario.

However when I make the functions a member of a class then I get errors. I have tried the following variations without success. Can someone please point me in the right direction - if I had had hair by now I wouldn't have anymore cause it would be on the floor all around me in clumps.

function definition:

```
void sdr_object::StreamACallback(short *xi, short *xq, sdrplay_api_StreamCbParamsT *params, unsigned int numSamples, unsigned int reset, void *cbContext)
{
...
}
```

Unsuccessful attempts to assign to structure include (including compiler error)

```
cbFns.StreamACbFn = this->StreamACallback;//"non standard syntax: use '&' to create a pointer to the member"
                                          //cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl sre_object::*)(...) to sdrplay_api_StreanCallback_t
cbFns.StreamACbFn = &this->StreamACallback;//'&': illegal operation on bound member function experssion

cbFns.StreamACbFn = this->sdr_object::StreamACallback; //"non standard syntax: use '&' to create a pointer to the member"
                                                       //cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl sre_object::*)(...) to sdrplay_api_StreanCallback_t
cbFns.StreamACbFn = &this->sdr_object::StreamACallback; //'&': illegal operation on bound member function experssion
```

Any wisdom will e received most gratefully. (How to do it will be received even more gratefully ...!)

Comment: what is `sdrplay_api_StreamCallback_t `? have you tried with a lambda?

Comment: Make your callbacks static member functions. Pass `this` pointer for `cbContext` parameter to `sdrplay_api_Init` - you get that same pointer back in the callback. Now the callback can do `static_cast<MyClass*>(cbContext)->memberFunction(params);` . The actual logic can now be implemented in a non-static member function; the static one just serves as a glue between C++ implementation and C API.

Comment: Igor's suggestion is the usual way this is done.  I say usual, because C++ programmers have come up with other methods of encapsulating this issue.  So there really isn't one hard, fast approach to this.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for your comment. It took me a little bit of time to get my brain around it and be able to implement it, however once I did it worked brilliantly - so a very big "thank you very much" for your answer - I would never have got there with out your input.

Could you please explain the operation of:
static_cast<MyClass*>(cbContext)->memberFunction(params);

If you can give some brief insight then I will write up your reply as the answer.

Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie could you be kind enough to suggest a different approach. It would be helpful to see an alternative. That said, you suggest that Igor's way is the usual way to do it, and, as I commented above, once I worked out how to implement it, it worked perfectly for me. However I now need to work out what Igor's suggestion is actually doing!

Comment: There's not much to explain, really. First, you take a `this` pointer to your class, convert it to `void*` (implicitly), and pass it to `sdrplay_api_Init`. The framework stashes it somewhere internally. Then, when the framework calls your callback, it passes that pointer as a parameter to the callback, where you convert it back to `MyClass*` (explicitly this time). Once you have access to the class instance, you can do anything with it - e.g. call member functions on it. The framework provides `void *cbContext` parameter for this specific purpose.

Comment: This is a common pattern for C-style APIs. I'm not actually familiar with the specific API you are using, but once I spotted that `void*` parameter, I went looking for the place where the application can provide one, and found `sdrplay_api_Init` (which is also where you register the callbacks).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have posted an answer based on your suggestion. Would you be kind enough to check what I have written - I would not want to post an unhelpful inaccurate answer.

By the way - one thing I do not understand in the implementation that the compiler accepts is that the pointer I pass to sdrplay_api_Init is a pointer to the function not the object. Yet in the static_cast I end up with a pointer to the object. That suggests that the API (or something else) converts the function pointer to the pointer of the thing that contains the function, which it then stores in cbContext.

Comment: You didn't show your `sdrplay_api_Init` call. What do you pass for the third (last) parameter there?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the line of code that calls sdrplay_api_Init is:  `if ((err = sdrplay_api_Init(chosenDevice->dev, &cbFns, NULL)) != sdrplay_api_Success)` - I have not changed that from the supplied example program, and the program still works in the object based version. The definition of the function is `sdrplay_api_Init(HANDLE dev, sdrplay_api_CallbackFnsT *callbackFns, void *cbContext);`

Comment: Then you are just fooling yourself. Since you pass `NULL` for `cbContext` parameter of `sdrplay_api_Init`, you are getting `NULL` for `cbContext` parameter in the callback, and are calling the member function through a `NULL` pointer. This exhibits undefined behavior, usually manifested as a crash. You are probably getting away with it because your member function doesn't actually access any member variables, and so never attempts to dereference `this` pointer (which, again, is `NULL`).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you for the correction. I tested what you said and the results of that verify what you suggest, in particular that I got away with it because I was not accessing any member variables. I added a counter as a member variable and without `this` in `sdrpaly_api_init` incementing the counter in the call back function caused a crash. Put `this` in as you suggested and all came good. That leads to another question - where/how did you get your fantastic expertise/knowledge/ability - I am impressed by the way you were able to understand and solve my problem and subsequent issues

Comment: Like I said, it's a common technique, encountered frequently in C-style APIs. I wouldn't remember where and how I learned it first - probably been decades ago - and I've seen it enough times since that the pattern is instantly recognizable.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes with many thanks to Igor Tandetnik who suggested the solution in comments above.

Igor wrote "Make your callbacks static member functions. Pass `this` pointer for `cbContext` parameter to `sdrplay_api_Init` - you get that same pointer back in the callback. Now the callback can do `static_cast<MyClass*>(cbContext)->memberFunction(params);` . The actual logic can now be implemented in a non-static member function; the static one just serves as a glue between C++ implementation and C API"

My implementation of that is as follows:

Add to the class declaration in the header file an intermediary "glue" function for each event handler e.g.:

```
static void sdr_object::StreamACallback_static(short *xi, short *xq, sdrplay_api_StreamCbParamsT *params, unsigned int numSamples, unsigned int reset, void *cbContext)
{
    static_cast<sdr_object*>(cbContext)->StreamACallback(xi, xq, params, numSamples, reset, cbContext);
};
```

For the function above, the pointer that is handed to the API then becomes

```
cbFns.StreamACbFn = this->StreamACallback_static;
```

In my particular example, I then had to do the same for the other two functions.

I did not have to change any other existing code.

Again, many thanks to Igor for the answer - I hope I have implemented it as he intended ... that said, what I have described works, so I imagine I have!